# AppOnlySequence sharepoint hosted app

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin

I have added an AppOnlySequence to my workflow and inside it there is a HttpSend activity which perform a GET operation on a **host web** list item.
But I don't get any response back.

Once I remove the AppOnlySequence the HttpSend works just fine.

I've also configured my environment according to following post.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
You have to enable "Allow the app to make app-only calls to Sharepoint" in AppManifest.xml under permissions.

Then the XML would look like this.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```